# Loading fixtures in sails tests

Tags: node.js, testing, sails.js

The [docs](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/Testing) just say

```
// here you can load fixtures, etc.
```

I've worked out that I can include

```
var fixtures = require('./fixtures/models.js');
```

in the bootstrap script, so the full bootstrap script is:

```
/*
 * Lifts Sails before testing comenses.
 */

var Sails = require('sails');
var sails;

before(function(done) {
  this.timeout(5000);

  Sails.lift({
    // configuration for testing purposes
    environment: 'test',
  }, function(err, server) {
    sails = server;
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }

    // here you can load fixtures, etc.
    var fixtures = require('./fixtures/models.js');
    done(err, sails);
  });
});

after(function(done) {
  // here you can clear fixtures, etc.
  Sails.lower(done);
});
```

I can then reference the fixtures var in the boot script, but I can't reference it in a test. I just get undefined.

Comment: You need to require the fixtures file on every test file.

Comment: @LuisElizondo Does that mean that the comment in the docs is wrong? Or am I miss reading it.

Comment: You can load the fixtures there, but you need to assign them to the sails object, or you can just require the file in every test file.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Barrels](https://github.com/bredikhin/barrels).

The package helps loading fixtures from files into the DB (whatever DB you choose)
And you can choose in which order they are loaded (associations populating)

To load the fixtures in the test I add at the top of the test file:

```
var Barrels = require('barrels');
var barrels = new Barrels(process.cwd()+'/tests/fixtures');
var fixtures = barrels.data;
```

after that in the test itself I prefer reseting the DB tables to the fixtures on before the test... like so:

```
before(function (done) {
      barrels.populate(['users', 'categories', 'products'], function (err) {
        if (err) return done(err);

        done();
      });
});
```

That's it. You have your DB populated.
This process fires all the events of 'creation' on all the models, so you can test that too.

You can use my version of that package which includes a mongodb ids support:
https://github.com/stuk88/barrels

Here is a full guide on how to test in sails:
https://github.com/bredikhin/sailsjs-mocha-testing-barrels-fixtures-example